# pug use i18n in the template file

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, pug

I registered i18n and set the pug as the view engine even added the helper function everything works, but when I call pugs compileFile I get function is not found error for the i18n '__'.

```
static initI18n(app) {
    i18n.configure({
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      directory: path.resolve('server/tools/locals'),
      locales: ['en', 'gr'],
      objectNotation: false,
      updateFiles: false
    });
    app.use(i18n.init);
}

  static initViewEngine(app) {
    app.set('view engine', 'pug');
    app.set('views', path.resolve('./'));
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.locals.__ = res.__ = function() {
        return i18n.__.apply(req, arguments);
      };    
      next();
    });
  }



var compiledHTML = pug.compileFile(template)({name: user.name});
```

in the pug file I am calling it like so

```
doctype html
html
  body()
    #{__('hello')}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template local i18n function `__` should be set on `res` or `req` when the `i18n.init` is registered. This means that the middleware in `initViewEngine` is irrelevant.

Also, calling `pug.compileFile` explicitly with the template defeats the purpose of having an *express* middleware.

To compile the template that way, you need to pass an implementation for `__` along as the template context.

```
const compiledHTML = pug.compileFile(template)({__: i18n.__});
```